# Graphical interface not logging in

Tags: xorg, freebsd, slim

I have installed the Simple Login Manager, `slim`as my login manager for xorg. I am using the Lumina desktop and FreeBSD 12.0.

> SLiM  is   a lightweight login manager for X11, allowing the
>   initialization of a graphical session by entring username and password in a login
>          screen.

I installed it with:

```
pkg install slim
```

Also placed into `/etc/rc.conf`

```
slim_enable="YES"
```

The graphical login interfaces does appear, however after inputing login and password, it gives the error `Failed to execute login command`.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested fix found in the a FreeBSD [forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/56405/) is to create a `~/.xinitrc` and call your desktop manager, lumina in my case, from it. The `.xinitnrc` also has to have the executable bit set.

As in:

```
cat << EOF > ~/.xinitrc
exec start-lumina-desktop
EOF

chmod a+x ~/.xinitrc
```

After this change, I am able to login using `slim`.